# viewWithTag return self

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview

I have a strange behavior with the function viewWithTag.
My storyboard look like that :

```
-viewController
--UIScrollView1 (should be a UIView but not changing yet)
---Object with tag 1 to 11
---Some other object with tag 0
--UIScrollView2 (should be a UIView but not changing yet)
---Object with tag 1 to 11
---Some other object with tag 0
```

I my code, I do [UIScrollView1 wiewWithTag:(1 to 11)] (each time cast as the good object and it work well.
I do the same with UIScrollView2 but viewWithTag return each time UIScrollView2, so I never match any tagged object.

Just for Debug purpose, I don't do UIScrollView2 update and try to update with some other value UIScrollView1, and the it return UIScrollView1 just for one object, a UIImageView (the only one).
But all the UILabel work fine again.

Did someone have some clues to help me ?

PS : The tag objects was checked like 10 times and I use a function like :
-(void) updateWithScroll:(UIScrollView*)myScroll
so it's the same as the 1 or the 2 :(

Thanks in advance,
Damien

Comment: Have the same behavior in ios8, i don't know why that happens. I use the same method to create some views, and the first run is ok and the next one crashes

Answer (score 1):

Try to browse the subviews by yourself, with fast enumeration of `subviews` or with another loop.

I ran into the same issue while I did not expect that behavior, but I have the choice to not keep the root view tag and set it to -1, a value never used.

Comment: So the solution will be loop inside the array of subviews and check each tag until find the good one ? As I guess should be what viewWithTag do. My code change to much so I can't try quickly, but sound a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume UIScrollView2's tag is 0, so the first view with tag 0 is your UIScrollView2 itself.

You probably should give a different tag for each subview of your UIScrollView2, and always different from the UIScrollView2's tag.

For example, you can keep 0 for you'r scrollView's tag, and 1,2,3... for it's subviews.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was waiting for answer and at the end design change and do not need to use it anymore. But interesting answer, I will try but you can't make `[UIScrollView2 wiewWithTag:1]` if you already have an object, whatever it is on UIScrollView1 with tag at 1 ?